# Multiple responsive images

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have four images in a vertically and horizontally centered div. I want these images to be on the same line fitting my div when the screen dimensions allow it. And if the screen is re-sized (or on a smart-phone), I want to have the first two on a line and the two others on a second line.

The behavior should be like this on a wide screen:

[image: on a wide screen]

turning into this on a tight screen:

[image: on a tight screen]

I don't know how to get this...

My html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="img1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="man1">
    <img src="img2.png" class="img-responsive" alt="man2">
    <img src="img3.png" class="img-responsive" alt="man3">
    <img src="img4.png" class="img-responsive" alt="man4">
</div>
```

and css:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    text-align: center;
}

.img-responsive {
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dh27U/)

Comment: did you try `display:inline-block` or `float:left` ?

Comment: Yes but I may be doing it the wrong way, I end up with a transition _3 images / 1_ and then with 2 images on the screen and have to scroll for the others

Comment: try setting up a http://jsfiddle.net showing your progress, you'll get more help that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possible solution without media queries:

I added a second level wrapper

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dJ25r/)**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    margin: 50px auto;
        width: 80%;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
}

.insideWrap {
    display:inline-block
}

.img-responsive {
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution but there is still the problem of the height. If I add `height: 100%;` to `.insideWrap` and `height: 80%;` to `.wrapper` it work when the 4 images are on the same line but on a smaller screen the height isn't adjusted and I have to scroll. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily solve tis with Media Queries. Take a look: [Media Queries for Standard Devices](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

You can define the image at half-screen size when screen width is less than 400px, per example.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    text-align: center;
}

.img-responsive {
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {

.img-responsive{
 width: 33%;
}

}
```

@[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enHeP/)

## :)

Comment: you should really provide an example in your answer. As is I'd consider this a comment, nothing more

Comment: nice answer +1 for improving

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do something as simple as this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.wrapper img {position:relative; float:left; width:25%; height: auto}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.wrapper img {position:relative; float:left; width:50%; height: auto}
}
```

The first part says: When the screen size is over 768px to make each image 25% the width of the containing div, thus 4 images could be displayed side by side.

The second part says: When the screen size is under 767px to make each image 50% the width of the containing div, thus 2 images would be displayed side by side.

The break points would obviously change based on your preference. I targeted your images without the .img-responsive class, but you can replace .wrapper img with .img-responsive if you prefer.

Comment: The transition _#### -> ##/##_ is done perfectly ! Thanks.
I still have to adapt the `height` so it always fit in the screen.